# Apple Carplay - how to create a playable container?

Tags: ios, carplay

According to the Apple docs for `MPContentItem.playable`:

> When set to YES, the designated content item is able to be played.
>   Containers and individual content items can set this property to YES.
>   For example, a playlist with multiple songs in it. The playlist is a
>   container that can be played, or the user could choose a song from
>   inside of the playlist.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpcontentitem/1620158-playable?language=objc

However, when I set a container to be playable, it ceases to be a container. When I tap it, it plays, so how could I ever see the listing of child items? When it plays it goes to now playing screen and then hitting back takes me back to where I tapped it (ie the top level listing) so I can never get to the second level listing.

So is the documentation wrong, or is it actually possible to create a playable container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working CarPlay for a while now. I'm pretty sure the documentation is wrong. You can't create a playable container.

Comment: Hi Can you please help me on this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59501929/472336